# Limiting DICOM tags

Tags: python-3.x, dicom, simpleitk

I am trying to limit the DICOM tags, which are retained, by using

```
for key in keys:
    if key.upper() not in {'0028|0010','0028|0011'}:
        image_slice.EraseMetaData(key)
```

in Python 3.6 where image_slice is of type SimpleITK.SimpleITK.Image

I then use

```
image_slice.GetMetaDataKeys()
```

to see what tags remain and they are the tags I selected.  I then save the image with

```
writer.SetFileName(outputDir+os.path.basename(sliceFileNames[i]))
writer.Execute(image_slice)
```

where outputDir is the output directory name and os.path.basename(sliceFileNames[i]) is the DICOM image name.  However, when I open the image, with Weasis or with MIPAV, I notice that there are a lot more tags than were in image_slice.  For example, there is

```
(0002,0001) [OB] FileMetaInformationVersion: binary data
(0002,0002) [UI] MediaStorageSOPClassUID:
(0002,0003) [UI] MediaStorageSOPInstanceUID:
(0008,0020) [DA] StudyDate: (which is given the date that the file was created)
```

I was wondering how, and where these additional tags were added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The group 2 tags you are seeing are meta data tags, that are always written while writing the dataset. Unless "regular" tags, which start with group 8, these group 2 tags do not belong to the dataset itself, but contain information about the encoding/writing of the dataset, like the transfer syntax - more information can be found in the [DICOM standard, part 10](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/html/part10.html#sect_7.1). They will be recreated on saving a dataset to a file, otherwise, the DICOM file would not be valid.

About the rest of the tags I can only guess, but they are probably written by the software because they are mandatory DICOM tags and have been missing in the dataset. `StudyDate` is certainly a mandatory tag, so adding it if it is missing is correct, if the data is seen as derived data (which it usually is if you are manipulating it with ITK). I guess the other tags that you didn't mention are also mandatory tags.

Someone with more `SimpleITK` knowledge can probably add more specific information.